# Indesign Export Paragraphs to text based csv

Tags: javascript, csv, adobe-indesign

We are trying to write a simple script to export all stories in an Indesign file
we have only two styles Headline, which is the headline of each article
and text, that is the body of the article
we wat to export to a csv file (text) so we can imported in a series of applications that we have like this:

> headline, Text (series of paragraphs)
>   "xxxxx","xxxxxxxxx x x x x xxx xxxxx xxxx xxx"
>   "xxxxx","xxxxxxxxx x x x x xxx xxxxx xxxx xxx"
>   "xxxxx","xxxxxxxxx x x x x xxx xxxxx xxxx xxx"

But we came out with a problem, when we try to write to a file the string variable of the "contents of the paragraphs" won't write to the file, we can display them in an alert dialog, but don't write them in a text file.

The problem is the line 46, we don't know if we have to strip some characters or transform the contents to a only text variable

Here is the code

```
//Exportascsv.js  
      var myStory, myParagraph, myParagraphTemp, myString, myTag, myStartTag;   var myEndTag, myTextStyleRange, myTable;  
      if(app.documents.length !=0){     if(app.documents.item(0).stories.length != 0){   //Open a new text file.  
    var myTextFile = File.saveDialog("Save CSV As", undefined);   //If the user clicked the Cancel button, the result is null.  
    if(myTextFile != null){   //Open the file with write access.  
      myTextFile.open("w");  
      var myCounterArt = 0;   //walk through the stories.  
      for(var myCounter = 0; myCounter < app.documents.item(0).stories.length; myCounter++){  
        myStory = app.documents.item(0).stories.item(myCounter);   // we have stories inside stories (articles in articles sometimes)  
        var myParagraphCounter = 0;  
        myParagraphTemp = "";  
        myString = "";  
        do{  
          myParagraph = myStory.paragraphs.item(myParagraphCounter);  
          myParagraphTemp = "";  
          switch(myParagraph.appliedParagraphStyle.name){   //Headline paragraph style  
              case "Headline":  
                myString = '"'+myParagraph.contents+'","';  
                myParagraphCounter++;  
                break;  
              case "Texto":   //Text paragraph style  
                myString = myString+myParagraph.contents;  
                myParagraphCounter++;  
                break;  
              default:  
                myParagraphCounter++;  
                break;  
          }  
        } while (myParagraphCounter < myStory.paragraphs.length)  
        myString = myString+'"';  
        myTextFile.writeln(myString);  
      }  
      myTextFile.write("\r");  
      myTextFile.close();  
    }     }   }
```

Comment: It was the encoding of the file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited some English issues in your post.  I have marked down teh data using > at the begining of the block and two spaces after each line.

Comment: Was the question solved?